# How can I solve the problem with forwarding messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, vk

I'm created a chat-bot using '**botact**' library, but
when I'm trying to verificate my **bot** on vk-community API working page I receive an error in '**Windows PowerShell**' (Here I started the server for bot):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fwd_messages' of undefined
 at Botact.getLastMessage (C:\Users\whoami\Desktop\Bot-test\node_modules\botact\lib\utils\getLastMessage.js:2:11)
    at Botact.module.exports (C:\Users\whoami\Desktop\Bot-test\node_modules\botact\lib\methods\listen.js:29:28).
```

**The file 'getLastMessage.js' contains this code:**

```
    const getLastMessage = (msg) => {
      if (msg.fwd_messages && msg.fwd_messages.length) {
        return getLastMessage(msg.fwd_messages[0])
      }

      return msg
    }

module.exports = getLastMessage
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to forward the msg.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty That's all code what i'm using for bot server. Mb i'm missing something?

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { Botact } = require('botact')

const server = express()

const bot = new Botact({
  token: 'token_for_my_group_i_just_hided_it',
  confirmation: 'code_for_my_group_i_just_hided_it'
})

**bot.on(function (ctx) {
  console.log(ctx.body)
})**

server.use(bodyParser.json())

server.post('/', bot.listen)

server.listen(80)

Comment: @iglebovvv can you console.log(msg) and add result here?

Comment: @Zrna I changed console.log argument on "msg":


**bot.on(function (ctx) {
  console.log(msg)
})**

but the same error appears:

**TypeError:** Cannot read property 'fwd_messages' of undefined
    at Botact.getLastMessage (C:\Users\whoami\Desktop\Bot-test\node_modules\botact\lib\utils\getLastMessage.js:2:11)
    at Botact.module.exports (C:\Users\whoami\Desktop\Bot-test\node_modules\botact\lib\methods\listen.js:29:28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know much about `botact` but according to the code when you are hitting the `/` route, you need to pass a body containing an `object` property.

Now as this is bot framework for `vk bots` maybe it automatically sends the request body. You can make sure by logging the request body.

```
server.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    console.dir(req.body);
    await bot.listen(req, res);
});
```

[/lib/methods/listen.js](https://github.com/bifot/botact/blob/master/lib/methods/listen.js):

```
const { type, secret, object, group_id } = framework === 'koa'
    ? args[0].request.body
    : args[0].body
...
...
...
const { events, middlewares } = actions
const forwarded = this.getLastMessage(object)
```

Now, when you do `bot.listen` express passes `req` as first argument. and `{ type, secret, object, group_id }` these fields get distructured from the `req.body`.

And then `object` is getting passed to the `getLastMessage` function.

So for the request body in minimum you would need

```
{ "object": {} }
```

Here is the `200 OK` output that I got after added that to the request body from Postman

[image: postman request example]

**POC Code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { Botact } = require("botact");
const server = express();
const bot = new Botact({
  token: "token_for_my_group_i_just_hided_it",
  confirmation: "code_for_my_group_i_just_hided_it"
});
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post("/",bot.listen);
server.listen(8080);
```